# Как написать generic-функцию?

Tags: typescript, typescript-типы

Начинаю изучать Typescript и самое большое затруднение вызывают дженерики. Есть простой код на JS, функция `wrapper` оборачивает другую функцию:

```
const innerFunc = (params) => {
    return params.p.toString();
};

const innerFunc2 = (params) => {
    return params.p;
};

const wrapper = (wrappedFunc) => {
    return (params) => {
        let { p } = params;

        p += 1;

        return wrappedFunc({ p });
    };
};

console.log(wrapper(innerFunc)({ p: 1 })); // выводит результат сложения двух чисел = 2
console.log(wrapper(innerFunc2)({ p: "1" })); // выводит результат объединения двух строк = 11
```

**Теперь этот пример на TypeScript:**

```
interface IBaseParams {
    p: number | string
}

interface IParams1 extends IBaseParams {
    p: number
}

interface IParams2 extends IBaseParams {
    p: string
}

type FuncType<T extends IBaseParams> = (params: T) => string;

const innerFunc: FuncType<IParams1> = (params) => {
    return params.p.toString();
};

const innerFunc2: FuncType<IParams2> = (params) => {
    return params.p;
};

const wrapper = (wrappedFunc) => {
    return (params) => {
        let { p } = params;

        p += 1;

        return wrappedFunc({ p });
    };
};
```

Не могу понять, как здесь описать функцию `wrapper`, чтобы она была дженериком? Буду благодарен за пояснения. Цель - разобраться, а не просто получить компилируемый код.

Comment: У вас какой-то очень непонятный и искусственный пример. В частности какого типа параметры ожидаются у функции которую возвращает wrapper и почему?

Comment: Пример действительно искусственный, учебный. Параметр - объект с единственным свойством p, которе может быть строкой или числом. Почему - мне так захотелось )

Answer (score 1):

```
interface IBaseParams { p: number | string }

interface IParams1 extends IBaseParams { p: number }
interface IParams2 extends IBaseParams { p: string }

type FuncType<T extends IBaseParams> = (params: T) => T['p'];
declare const innerFunc_1: FuncType<IParams1>;
declare const innerFunc_2: FuncType<IParams2>;

type $wrappedFunc = FuncType<IParams1> | FuncType<IParams2>
declare const wrapper: <T extends $wrappedFunc>(wrappedFunc: T)
    => (...params: Parameters<T>)
        => ReturnType<T>

test: {
    const res = wrapper(innerFunc_1)({ p: 1 })
}
test: {
    const res = wrapper(innerFunc_2)({ p: "1" })
}
```

---

> Цель - разобраться

1. Читай.

   - Читай чужой код.
   - Читай https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped
2. Пиши.

   - Пиши но сильно не зацикливайся
   - Пиши но не реализуй, описывай только логику, только `declare`.
3. Спрашивай.

   - Оформляй здесь вопросы.
   - Cпрашивай в комментариях.
   - И главное не забывай метку [typescript-типы](/questions/tagged/typescript-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%8b).
4. Делись. Делись своими знаниями. gl ;)

Comment: рекомендую тему для следующего вопроса: на примере каких библиотек стоит ознакомиться с typescript / typescript generics. что такое `@types`

Comment: `// @ts-expect-error` - для тестов может пригодиться

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Но что-то мозг плавится :) мне не понятно, как описать реализацию сего на TS. Хотя бы вот возьмем первую `innerFunc_1`, упростим код вот так: `interface IParams { p: number };
type FuncType<T extends IParams> = (params: T) => T['p'];
const innerFunc_1: FuncType<IParams> = (params: IParams) => {
    return params.p.toString();
}` - исходя из `FuncType` на выходе ожидается `number`, но `innerFunc` должна вернуть строку.

Comment: ну да, `T['p']` - что пришло то и ушло

Comment: (С) `({ p: 1 })); // выводит результат сложения двух чисел = 2` `number` так что не понимаю почему "должна вернуть строку"

Comment: в первом тесте `res` будет `number` в втором - `string` если навести мышку (в VSCode или в песочнице) - это будет видно

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ - sandbox